# Html img loader gif called twice during request AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to put gif loader before real image loaded from ajax, but during ajax request, seems like gif loader called twice. How to make gif loader not loaded twice like on gif image below

[image]

HTML:

```
<img src="/images/loader/loading.gif" style="width:60%" id="qrCode">
```

AJAX:

```
function QRcode(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>/load-qr',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    data: {
        csrf_token : $('input[name=csrf_token]').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#qrCode").attr("src", data.qrcode);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(xhr.status + "\n" + xhr.responseText + "\n" + thrownError);
    }
  });
}
```

I call QRcode function inside `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: ...and when you comment out the call to `QRcode()`, the effect goes away?

Comment: QR code not appear, only loading

Comment: Yes, but the "gif loader called twice" effect is gone? If that's the case, then your real `QRcode()` function sets the loader GIF. Your sample function in the question above does not. Are you sure you're showing the function 100% as it is?

Comment: Yes, gif loader effect is gone, it's replaced with qr code image, i'm showing the function 100%. Loader effect replaced with qr code image by element id qrCode

Comment: check how many times same function gets called .

Comment: I only call that function once inside $(document).ready(function() { });

Comment: Try the following. Set the source to empty in the HTML. `<img src="">`. Use `$("#qrCode").attr("src", "/images/loader/loading.gif");` in the `QRcode()` function, before the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: @Tomalak, Broken image -> gif loader twice -> qr code